# Merge replication 'A Security error occurred'

Tags: merge, replication

I have a merge replication configured with a publication and a distributor ruining on the same machine- SQL Server 2012 and Windows server 2008. The replication used to work fine for the past 4 months. But now when I open the monitoring window to check the status, it says "A Security error occurred" on all three subscribers and now it is not replicating.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I've seen this error before when using Merge Replication over Web Synchronization.  Usually it is an issue with the certificate or a configuration issue.

Comment: Tnx Brandon. You are right the ssl had expired. I updated it with the new ssl and it worked. tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this error before when using Merge Replication over Web Synchronization. Usually it is an issue with the certificate or a configuration issue.